# Android: Randomly Drawing Box inside a Path

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have ZShape and drawing it on Canvas. Now i want to add different shapes (rectangle, circle etc) inside Zshape RANDOMLY. I need the random function which gives me random location within the path without overlapping the already drawn (rectangle, circle etc) Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

if you are looking for random no. Generation then You can use something like this:-

```
  Random random=new Random();
 int randomNo=random.nextInt(4);

 switch (number) {
    case 0:

        //Work for your ractangle

        break;
    case 1:
        //work for your circle
        break;

    case 2:
        //.....
        break;
    case 3:
        //....
        break;


    }

}
```

Comment: its not just random number generation rather drawing random shape inside an area.